# Laravel 4 - How to fetch models with skip() / take() but no where clause

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am currently developing an API with Laravel 4 and ran into an issue when trying to filter a list of users returned. What confuses me is, that the L4 docs say

> Note: All methods available on the query builder are also available when querying Eloquent models.

Now some code to clearify things:

```
    $since = Input::has('since') ? strtotime(Input::get('since')) : 0;
    $skip = (int)Input::get('skip');
    $take = (int)Input::get('take');

    if ($since) {
        $builder = User::where('updated_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $since));
    }
    else {
        $builder = new User();
    }

    if ($take > 0) {
        $builder->take($take);
    }
    if ($skip > 0 && $take > 0) {
        $builder->skip($skip);
    }

    return count($builder->get());
```

As you can see I am trying to fetch models based on different criteria. Whenever the URL parameter **since** is provided, I intended to return users modified since the given datetime.

The problem is, that the 'skip' and 'take' parameters do not work with no 'since' set. Assuming there are 3 users in the database, the API returns

- skip=1&take=10                          => 3 users
- since=2013-06-06 11:00:00skip=1&take=10 => 1 user ( 2 have updated_at > 2013-06-06 11:00:00, but one is skipped )

Shouldn't it return 2 users in the first case ( 3 in table, first skipped )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `new User` You're creating new model. Try `User::newQuery()`. It should return query builder for User model.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 

The newQuery() method indeed solved the problem. 

One note: this method is not static, so I have to call it on a User instance:


`$user = new User();

$builder = $user->newQuery();`

Comment: I wasn't sure if that method was static or not. Glad it helped :)

Comment: As of Laravel 5.2, there is an equivalent static method simply called `query`. `$builder = User::query();`